# Using kUTTypePDF in a Share Extension only provides local URL, not web URL?

Tags: swift

My app saves the URL from Safari using a Share Extension. However, when the site is a pdf type file I notice that using the kUTTypePDF identifyer the resulting URL is a local URL instead of the web URL. Does anyone know how to obtain the web URL file from a pdf file type?  Note: using kUTTypeURL or "public URL" works for the standard html file, but will not work if it is a pdf file.  Code is below.  The resulting linkURL = String(describing: shareURL) is a local URL (file:// ..., not https://www...)

```
private func handleSharedFile() {
  // extracting the path to the URL that is being shared
    recTypeS = "xxx"
    let contentType1 = kUTTypeImage as String
    let contentType2 = kUTTypeURL as String
    let contentType3 = kUTTypePDF as String
    
    guard
   
    let items = extensionContext?.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem],
        let item = items.first,
        let attachments = item.attachments        
    else {           
        print("no items found")
        return}
    
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 2) // allows 2 threads at a time
    print("** Attachements Found: ",attachments.count)

        if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType3) {
            attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType3,
                              options: nil) { [unowned self] (url, error) in
            // Handle the error here if you want
            guard error == nil else {
               //
                return }
                 
            if let shareURL = url as? NSURL{
                
                linkURL = String(describing: shareURL) // This results in local URL (file:// ..., not https://www...)
                let sufType = getSuffix(fileName: linkURL)
                print("shareURL=",shareURL)
                print("suffix=",sufType)
                guard let nurl = URL(string: String(describing: shareURL)) else {return}
                let session = URLSession.shared
                session.dataTask(with: nurl) { (data, response, err) in
                    if let response = response {
                        print(response)
                    }
                    if let data = data{
                        //print(data)
                        let datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                        //datF = datastring as String? ?? ""
                
                        recTypeS = ".pdf"
                            let document = PDFDocument(data: data)
                            pdfView.document = document
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .nVersion, object: self) // updates VC
                        }
                } .resume()
            } else {
              print("Could not load URL")
              // Handle this situation as you prefer
              fatalError("Impossible to load image")
            }
            print("url found")
            semaphore.signal()
            } // closure
        } // end if type URL
       
        
    } // loop
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + 1.0)
    //print(String(describing: image))
    //print(String(describing: url))
    if recTypeS == "xxx" {
        print("no valid type")
        //extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    } else { print("valid type found")}
}
```

Comment: `kUTTypeImage`, `kUTTypeURL`, `kUTTypePDF` are deprecated you should use `"public.image"`, `"public.url"`, `"com.adobe.pdf"` instead

Comment: Btw what's wrong with `url`? Where is your resource located? Can you print your `url` and post it to your question?

Comment: Currently the kUTType.. and "public..." work identically. When a pdf file is proccessed as "com.adobe.pdf" or kUTTypePDF, the file is automattically copied to a local tmp file. In. the code given the variable linkURL obtains the pdf URL. The result is a local file not a web URL. For example file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F736656A-3F4C-4EE9-9965-7A234FC5EA05/data/Containers/Data/Application/E8AF35F7-9779-4038-B042-27F0A82334DD/tmp/QuickLookContent-pBpG1WYS/FAQ24TAVJU-Installation-Manual.pdf

Comment: I never said it should make a difference. I said it is deprecated.